# how to copy or match only selected elements from an XML input with namespace and then remove the namespace at the same time

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

Given below is my XML input. How do I copy or match selected elements that I want to reflect in my XML output using XSL.

The general idea of the logic should be to specify only the elements I am interested instead of specifying the elements that I don't like to be included in the output. The elements that I want to reflect in my output XML are always present in the XML Inpput. The rest of the elements vary depending on what the system has generated and so I cannot just specify what to remove.

I was able to this without the namespace from the input by doing the copy-of, but when the namespace is present the code is not working.

I found a way to remove the namespace but when combined with the copy-of, didn't work as well. I am quite confused as to how XSL behaves.

Please bear with my inquiry, I'm very new to XML and XSL and I was assigned to this task because no one from our team had the experience working with XML. Thank you in advance.

XML Input:

```
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.test.com/rdc.xsd">
    <Transaction>
        <StoreName id="aa">STORE A</StoreName>
        <TransNo>TXN0001</TransNo>
        <RegisterNo>REG001</RegisterNo>
        <Items>
            <Item id="1">
                <ItemID>A001</ItemID>
                <ItemDesc>Keychain</ItemDesc>
            </Item>
            <Item id="2">
                <ItemID>A002</ItemID>
                <ItemDesc>Wallet</ItemDesc>
            </Item>
        </Items>
        <IDONTLIKETHIS_1>
            <STOREXXX>XXX</STOREXXX>
            <TRANSXXX>YYY</TRANSXXX>
        </IDONTLIKETHIS_1>
        <IDONTLIKETHIS_2>
            <STOREXXX>XXX</STOREXXX>
            <TRANSXXX>YYY</TRANSXXX>
        </IDONTLIKETHIS_2>
    </Transaction>
</Transaction>
```

Desired Output:

```
<Transaction>
    <Transaction>
        <StoreName id="aa">STORE A</StoreName>
        <TransNo>TXN0001</TransNo>
        <RegisterNo>REG001</RegisterNo>
        <Items>
            <Item id="1">
                <ItemID>A001</ItemID>
                <ItemDesc>Keychain</ItemDesc>
            </Item>
            <Item id="2">
                <ItemID>A002</ItemID>
                <ItemDesc>Wallet</ItemDesc>
            </Item>
        </Items>
    </Transaction>
</Transaction>
```

I've tried the code below but the problem with it is that I'm missing the second Transaction element and the xmlns attribute is present in the root element:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node()[not(self::*)]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>      
</xsl:template>   
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="x:Transaction/x:StoreName"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="x:Transaction/x:TransNo"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="x:Transaction/x:RegisterNo"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="x:Transaction/x:Items"/>
 </xsl:copy>      
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation uses a list of all names of elements that we want to copy after processing**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://invia.fujitsu.com/RetailDATACenter/rdc.xsd">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="pNames" select=
    "'|Transaction|StoreName|TransNo|RegisterNo|Items|Item|ItemID|ItemDesc'"/>

    <xsl:template match="*" >
     <xsl:if test=
      "contains($pNames,
                concat('|',local-name(), '|')
              )">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
     </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::*)]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.test.com/rdc.xsd">
    <Transaction>
        <StoreName id="aa">STORE A</StoreName>
        <TransNo>TXN0001</TransNo>
        <RegisterNo>REG001</RegisterNo>
        <Items>
            <Item id="1">
                <ItemID>A001</ItemID>
                <ItemDesc>Keychain</ItemDesc>
            </Item>
            <Item id="2">
                <ItemID>A002</ItemID>
                <ItemDesc>Wallet</ItemDesc>
            </Item>
        </Items>
        <IDONTLIKETHIS_1>
            <STOREXXX>XXX</STOREXXX>
            <TRANSXXX>YYY</TRANSXXX>
        </IDONTLIKETHIS_1>
        <IDONTLIKETHIS_2>
            <STOREXXX>XXX</STOREXXX>
            <TRANSXXX>YYY</TRANSXXX>
        </IDONTLIKETHIS_2>
    </Transaction>
</Transaction>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Transaction>
   <Transaction>
      <StoreName id="aa">STORE A</StoreName>
      <TransNo>TXN0001</TransNo>
      <RegisterNo>REG001</RegisterNo>
      <Items>
         <Item id="1">
            <ItemID>A001</ItemID>
         </Item>
         <Item id="2">
            <ItemID>A002</ItemID>
         </Item>
      </Items>
   </Transaction>
</Transaction>
```

**Do note**: One advantage of this solution over other possible solution is that the string containing the pipe-delimited list of element names can be provide as an externally-specified parameter to the transformation, making it very powerful and flexible and eliminating the need to alter the code any time we include new elements (or exclude some) from our white-list.

Comment: hi @dimitre, thank you so much for this. I feel kinda stupid coz I already came accross about the idea of checking the local-name vs the element but I don't know the syntax...if it would have been Java :) ... I also tried something similar to what Ken posted above, just not sure why I didn't get it right. Guess i'm panicking. Both your code and Ken's worked, would you be kind enough to explain the difference between using the namespace and not in the xsl transform?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really wanted to learn more about XML and XSL, I'm intrigued by it. Just don't have that much time right now coz I have tons of things to do. Thanks again. :)

Comment: oops didn't see that you already put an explanation at the bottom. thanks again

Comment: @Amy: You are welcome. Please, feel free to ask any questions and I'd be happy to answer -- just let me know via comments that you have a new question that you want me to look into. XSLT programming is something really fascinating and is well worth the effort of learning.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">
  <xsl:variable name="allowed">
    <names>
      <name>Transaction</name>
      <name>StoreName</name>
      <name>TransNo</name>
      <name>RegisterNo</name>
      <name>Items</name>
      <name>Item</name>
      <name>ItemID</name>
      <name>ItemDesc</name>
      <name>id</name>
    </names>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="comment()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:if test="local-name(.) = $allowed//name">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you need, but please read up on namespaces as I'm not sure that what you plan to do is all that sensible.

Hope this helps,

Ken

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:abc="http://www.test.com/rdc.xsd" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/> 

<xsl:template match="abc:Transaction|abc:StoreName|abc:TransNo|abc:RegisterNo|abc:Items|abc:Item|abc:ItemID|abc:ItemDesc">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}"> 
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*"> 
    <xsl:copy/> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="*"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: hi @ken, yes I read on this. I really wanted to learn more about XML and XSL. Just can't right now coz I have tons to do. I already tried similar to yours but I just didn't get the correct syntax. Thank you so much...I learned something new today :)

Comment: You're welcome.  Please note that this solution could also be paramaterised - it is effectively doing the same thing in a slightly different way.

Comment: By the way, Dimitri's solution seems to be using the real namespace rather than a test one.  Not sure if you want that to be public or not.